# Issues with custom getters and setters to retrieve and store values into a data dictionary

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm having issues with my app crashing when getting/setting primitive data types and instance methods don't run and only return null values.

I am trying to implement a system that allows me to create an object for subclassing use, mark some properties with the `@dynamic` tag, and have those dynamic properties set their values into and retrieve their values from a dictionary of data.

Currently in my original object I used the following methods to override the getting of properties

```
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSString *sel = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    if ([sel rangeOfString:@"set"].location == 0) {
        return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"v@:@"];
    } else {
        return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"@@:"];
    }
    return [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    NSString *key = NSStringFromSelector([invocation selector]);
    key = [key lowercaseString];

    if ([key rangeOfString:@"set"].location == 0) {
        key = [key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [key length]-4)];

        __unsafe_unretained id obj;
        [invocation getArgument:&obj atIndex:2];

        [self.data setObject:obj forKey:key];

    } else {
        id obj = [self.data objectForKey:key];

        if (obj) {
            [invocation setReturnValue:&obj];
        }

    }
}
```

This has worked almost perfectly, however when I try to set and store and `int`s, `long`s, or `BOOL`s, my application crashes with the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0xd)
```

When I use instance methods, they simply aren't run. Any logs I put in them don't output to the console, and all return values default to null. I understand this to be because I overwrote message forwarding, however it is the only way I found to implement this data structure system.

Additionally, I initially thought that the message overriding would only affect properties that I declared @dynamic, however I have come to understand that this is not the case.

If anyone could help me with the primitive data crashes, the instance method resolution, and having this selector only apply to properties I define, I would be greatly in their debt.

Thank you for your time even if you chose not to or are unable to help me.

Comment: You shouldn't be taking the address of `obj` when setting the return value: `[invocation setReturnValue:&obj];` should be `[invocation setReturnValue:obj];` I don't understand how primitives come into this; you can't be storing primitives in an `NSDictionary`, so where are you interacting with them?

Comment: If I want to set a primitive property of the object, it goes into the message forwarding chain and crashes.